# Rails MetaSearch Associations Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, meta-search

I am working with a rails app and have begun to work on a search function using metasearch but I am having troubles getting the correct method for the search.

For example I have a model (Proposal) that has a field cost.

```
..model/proposal.rb

class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :users, :through => :invitations
attr_accessible :cost, :user_id
```

For which this code works fine with meta search

```
..views/homes/live_requests.html.erb

<%= form_for @search, :url => "/live_requests", :html => {:method => :get} do |
<%= f.label :cost_greater_than %>
<%= f.text_field :cost_greater_than %><br />
<!-- etc... -->
<%= f.submit %>
```

Yet with a more complicated association I can not manage to get the meta search path correct.

I am trying to search over:

```
Proposal.last.user.suburb.name #Returns the name of the suburb as expected
```

I have tried many associations but cannot find the right one.

Proposal has a user_id field which maps to user
So Proposal.user returns a User
User then has a suburb_id which returns a suburb
Suburb has a field called name which returns a string

How would I work this into a metasearch form?

```
<%= f.text_field :user_user_suburb_name %>
or
<%= f.text_field :user_id_suburb_id_name %>
```

I cannot come to a solid conclusion.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I know its very simple, I just needed a deeper explanation of how it works, such that I can roll it out for the other parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was simply following the correct names as declared by the models.

Ie. in the model above, ensuring that it was User, not users etc.